# Given Z is a standardized random variable, why $E(ZZ^T)=I_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Z is a random variable. If $E(Z)=0$ and $\operatorname{var}(Z)=I_p$, and all moments involved are finite.

How to see $E(ZZ^T)=I_p$ and $E(ZZ^T|Y)=\operatorname{var} (Z|Y) + E(Z|Y)E(Z^T|Y)$?

By the definition of variance, I find $\operatorname{var} (Z)=E(Z-\mu)(Z-\mu)^T=E(ZZ^T)$. Now I am clear about the first equation. But how to get the second equation?

Some update: $Z$ is a standardized random variable. $E(ZZ^T|Y)=\operatorname{var} (Z|Y) + E(Z|Y)E(Z^T|Y)$ is a step of big proof of some specific statistical properties. In the original proof, the book says "Because $E(ZZ^T|Y)=\operatorname{var} (Z|Y) + E(Z|Y)E(Z^T|Y)$". I don't understand why this equation holds. The author thought this equation is natural without any explanation. But it's not obvious for me.

**One question is** how to interpret $E(Z|Y)$? I know it's a function of Y. But $E(Z)=0$, can I say  $E(Z|Y)=0$ also? I am confused.

Update:

Following  Toby Bartels's hint, by the definition

$$\operatorname{var} (X|Y)=E( (X-E(X|Y)) (X-E(X|Y))^T |Y) = E( (X-E(X|Y))  (X^T-E(X|Y)^T)     |Y)$$

It contains 4 terms after splitting:

1st term: $E(XX^T|Y)$

2nd term: $-E(X  E(X|Y)^T  |Y) = -E(X|Y)^T E(X|Y)$

3rd term: $-E(  E(X|Y) X^T |Y   )=-E(X|Y)E(X^T |Y)$

4th term: $E(   E(X|Y) E(X|Y)^T      |Y) = E(X|Y) E(X|Y)^T$

I am confused on the notation $E(X|Y)^T$. Can I claim $E(X|Y)^T = E(X|Y)$? I know in matrix algebra, if $E(X|Y)$ is a scalar, then obviously its transpose is the same. But here, I don't know the dimension of $E(X|Y)^T$.

Comment: Give context and what you tried. Otherwise the question is going to be closed.

Comment: Follows from the **definition** of variance.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you. By the definition of variance, I find $\operatorname{var} (Z)=E(Z-\mu)(Z-\mu)^T=E(ZZ^T)$. Now I am clear about the first equation. But how to get the second equation?

Comment: Try the definition of conditional variance; and remember that things like $ \mathrm E ( Z \mid Y ) $ are constants and can be pulled out of linear operators (such as $ \mathrm E $ again) (but be sure to keep multiplication in the correct order since presumably these are matrices).

Comment: By the way, I only saw this by going through closed questions that have been edited.  If you want to keep this open so that more people can see it, then clarifying that these are matrix-valued random variables (or whatever they are if that's not it) would be useful context (basically don't introduce generic symbols like $ Z $ and $ Y $ without saying what type of object they refer to); and showing how you tried to use the definitions and got stuck would be useful in showing where you need help.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Can you tell me why $E(ZZ^T|Y)=\operatorname{var} (Z|Y) + E(Z|Y)E(Z^T|Y)$?

Comment: @TobyBartels I think I said in a clear way that $Z$ is a standardized random variable. $E(ZZ^T|Y)=\operatorname{var} (Z|Y) + E(Z|Y)E(Z^T|Y)$ is a step of big proof of some specific statistical properties. In the original proof, the book says "Because $E(ZZ^T|Y)=\operatorname{var} (Z|Y) + E(Z|Y)E(Z^T|Y)$". I don't understand why this equation holds.

Comment: I think that the edits help; I've voted to reopen, so hopefully you can get some answers soon.

Comment: In the meantime: $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) $ is a function on the spectrum of $ Y $; its value at $ y $ is $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y = y ) $, that is $ \int _ x x \, \mathrm P ( X = x \mid Y = y ) $.  But you don't actually need that here, as long as you understand that it's linear, so that $ \mathrm E ( a _ 1 X _ 1 + a _ 2 X _ 2 \mid Y ) = a _ 1 \mathrm E ( X _ 1 \mid Y ) + a _ 2 \mathrm E ( X _ 2 \mid Y ) $ for constants $ a _ 1 $ and $ a _ 2 $ and random variables $ X _ 1 $ and $ X _ 2 $.  Oh, and also that $ \mathrm E ( a \mid Y ) = a $ for a constant $ a $, I guess.  …

Comment: …  What you do need the definition of, is conditional variance in terms of conditional expectation, which is: $ \operatorname { Var } ( X \mid Y ) = \mathrm E \Bigl ( \bigl ( X - \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) \bigr ) \bigl ( X - \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) \bigr ) ^ \top \; \Bigm | \; Y \Bigr ) $.  So if you expand the product, split the expectation into terms, and pull out all of the constants, then you should get $ \operatorname { Var } ( X \mid Y ) = \mathrm E ( X X ^ \top \mid Y ) - \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) \mathrm E ( X ^ \top \mid Y ) $ (which is simpler to work with anyway).

Comment: @TobyBartels thank you. I keep updating the question. I am confused on the notation $E(X|Y)^T$. Can I claim $E(X|Y)^T = E(X|Y)$? I know in matrix algebra, if $E(X|Y)$ is a scalar, then obviously its transpose is the same. But here, I don't know the dimension of $E(X|Y)^T$.

Comment: $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) $ has the same dimensions as $ X $.  (Well, technically $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) $ is a function, and its values have the same dimensions as $ X $.)  You can see that from the definition $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y = y ) = \int _ x x \mathrm P ( X = x \mid Y = y ) $; the $ x $ here is a value of $ X $ (so the same dimensions as $ X $, while $ \mathrm P ( X = x \mid Y = y ) $ is a scalar-valued measure, so we're integrating a matrix and getting a matrix.  …

Comment: …  Since transpose is linear, we actually have $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) ^ \top = \mathrm E ( X ^ \top \mid Y ) $, although you don't actually need this fact.  You can finish by simply cancelling the second and fourth terms.  (It doesn't look like they cancel, but that's because you reversed the order of multiplication in the second term.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Thanks. Now I am clear about this question. But I think $E(X|Y)$ has the same dimension as Y, not same as X, since it is a function of Y. Thus, suppose y can be 1,3,5, then $E(X|Y)$ has three corresponding functions of y.

Comment: If $ Y $ is a scalar-valued random variable that can take the three values $ 1 $, $ 3 $, and $ 5 $, then $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) $ is a function with three values, yes.  But if $ X $ is a $ p $-by-$ p $ matrix-valued random variable, then each value of this function is a $ p $-by-$ p $ matrix; that is, $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y = 1 ) $ is a $ p $-by-$ p $ matrix, $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y = 3 ) $ is a $ p $-by-$ p $ matrix, and $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y = 5 ) $ is a $ p $-by-$ p $ matrix.  These are the matrices whose transposes are being taken in $ \mathrm E ( X \mid Y ) ^ \top $.

Comment: @TobyBartels so maybe a more precise way to say is that $E(X|Y)$ has the same dimensions as $X$, for each value $Y=y$?

Comment: Yes, that should work.